# Show full-path for links

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, symbolic-link, hard-link

[image]

The real path for the folder `TEMP DESK` is:

> /home/username/Desktop/***Dropbox/mystuff***/TEMP DESK

But when I click on the link that I created for it, it shows:

> /home/username/Desktop/Link to TEMP DESK

Even if I do ctrl+L it still shows me this fake path...

How do I create a link such that when I click on it, it takes me to the real location where the target exists.

PS: I use "make link" option. Not sure if it creates a symbolic link or hard link and also not sure if it matters in this case (?)

Comment: It is not "fake", that is actually the REAL path of the folder. By creating a link, you can reach the same folder in two ways. And both paths are not fake.

Comment: Hmmm... But if I delete the original folder, then all the content will be deleted. If I delete the link, the original folder remains intact. Maybe "fake" isn't the best word, but there is for sure a difference between the two...

Comment: Sure, one is a link to the other :) I don't understand in which scenario you would like to "unfold" this link. A link from a folder to the other is such that you would never need such a thing, since you can reach all that you want from both paths.