# Nautilus: Visited directory via symlink, now I can't go one level up in the target directory hierarchy

Tags: nautilus, symbolic-link

I created a shortcut via "make link" option. When I enter to this shortcut's folder I can't see any folders above it so I can't easily navigate to them.

Is there a way to go one folder up in the GUI? Maybe a hotkey? (Can't do `cd ..` this time ^__^ ).

[image]

---

In Windows for example I am indeed able to navigate in the way I describe, here is a Win10 image that explains it:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Backspace key?

Comment: In nautilus less than 3.16 it's easy to add a parent button to nautilus toolbar though has to be done via the source > rebuild (patch or a ppa build for 14.04 available) Otherwise try `Alt+up key`

Comment: Alt+Up brings me from the link's destination to the desktop... So sadly no :\ If someone here have the right connections he might offer this directly to the dev team? I've very new so I can't really offer it directly, without the data have to pass through many people (I guess)...

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. Maybe try Jacob's solution or create links yourself. Your current links are seen as a directory so up is the dir. the link is in, typically the Desktop. If you create links using an executable  .desktop file  then navigation after using that 'link' will be normal.

Comment: Same question here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/713397/show-full-path-for-links (if solved, to mark other as duplicate)

Comment: Why not just press Control-L? That will let you type in the path.

Comment: @cat You might want to re- read the question. Opened from a link, the displayed path is not the *real* path.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Why this is a challenging question

The question has a few challenges:

- `nautilus` does not communicate directly from the command line, to get the currently active directory for example, nor can you "send" the currently opened folder (-window) to another directory from the command line.
- In the current path, as requested via `"NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"`, Nautilus does not return the *real* path to the current folder, but "sees" the link as if it was an actual folder.

The solution therefore is as dirty as it gets; we need to find workarounds. Below four options to solve the issue.

### 1. right- click to go one level up

To get the *real* path to the current directory, we have to retrieve information from the link. We can do that either by using `ls -l` on the link, which will output e.g.:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jacob jacob 35 jan 15 08:23 /home/jacob/Bureaublad/Flyer_st/Verwijzing naar Site_current -> /home/jacob/Bureaublad/Site_current
```

where the section after `->` is the *real* path inside the symlink, or, using `python`:

```
real = os.path.realpath("/path")
```

Using this in a `nautilus` script, we can indirectly get the *real* path to the current file or folder.

#### Then if we have the path, how do we make nautilus move one level up?

Again, we cannot solve this *and* keep our hands clean. To move one level up, we first edit the found path a bit, from:

```
/path/to/a/folder
```

into

```
/path/to/a
```

then, using `xdotool` to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (the GUI shortcut to insert a path into a nautilus window, since there is no cli option to move to another directory *using the current window*), and subsequently make `xclip` paste the edited path + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, we have a working solution!

#### In practice

1. We are in a folder, opened from a link ("Link to Telegram") on my Desktop. The *real* folder is a sub folder of my `Downloads` folder:

   [image]
2. Then if we right- click on *any* of the files inside the folder to run the script:

   [image]
3. Automatically, the path to the superior directory is inserted:

   [image]
4. And, also automatically, <kbd>Return</kbd> is pressed, and we move one directory level up:

   [image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

current = os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI").replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ")
real = os.path.realpath(current)
up = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(real, os.pardir))
run("xdotool key Control_L+l")
run("printf '"+up+"' | xclip -selection clipboard")
run("xdotool key Control_L+v")
# confirm by virtually press Return
time.sleep(0.1)
run("xdotool key Return")
```

#### How to set up

1. The script needs both `xdotool` and `xclip`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool xclip
   ```
2. create, if it doesn't exist already, the directory

   ```
   ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
   ```
3. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `level_up` (no extension) in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`, and ***make it executable***
4. You might have to log out and back in.
5. Now you should be able to run the script by right- click *on a file* (any) > scripts > level_up:

   [image]

---

[**EDIT**] I changed the script above to *paste* the path into the `nautilus` window, instead of making `xdotool` *type* it. It `needs` `xclip` to be installed, but it is a major improvement, especially on very long paths.

---

### 2. Alternatively, open a new nautilus window in the superior directory

You *could* avoid using `xdotool`, by making the script open a *new* nautilus window, in the parent's directory. The script would then be even shorter:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd)

current = os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI").replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ")
real = os.path.realpath(current)
up = real[:real.rfind("/")]
subprocess.Popen(["nautilus", up])
```

In this case, you wouldn't need to install `xdotool`. We could even extend the script by closing the original window and placing the new window exactly in the same position (& size).

The downside is that the history of the original window is lost this way.

### 3. An additional solution: alternative way to (automatically) create links

Not relevant to existing links, but when used from the GUI, a nautilus script to automatically create executable `.desktop` files on right-click might be helpful:

*right-click on the directory to create a shortcut (behaving as a link)*

[image]

Unlike symlinks, these links will take you to the actual folder, without behaving as a folder itself:

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

current = os.getenv(
    "NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
    ).replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ").strip()

if os.path.isdir(current):
    parent = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current, os.pardir))
    fldr_path = '"'+current+'"'
    folder = current[current.rfind("/")+1:]
    linkfilename = parent+"/"+folder+"link.desktop"
    linkdata = [
        "[Desktop Entry]",
        "Type=Application",
        "Name=Link to -> "+folder,
        "Icon=folder",
        "Exec=nautilus "+fldr_path,
        ]
    with open(linkfilename, "wt") as wt:
        for l in linkdata:
            wt.write(l+"\n")
    command = "chmod +x "+"'"+linkfilename+"'" 
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `make_link` (no extension) in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`, and ***make it executable***
2. Use the script by choosing it as a right- click option as in the first image. An executable `.desktop` file will be created in the same directory, move it elsewhere if you need to; the linked path is absolute.

#### Give the link an distinguishing icon

You could give the alternative link a distinguishing icon. If you search inside the directory `/usr/share/icons` for "folder", numerous valid options pop up.

If in the script the line `"Icon=folder",` is replaced by `Icon=stock_folder-copy,` (use the icon name without extension), the result on my system is:

[image]

Of course you can use your own custom icon as well, but if you use full paths (don't use `~`), you *should* include the icon's extension.

### 4. Move to the superior directory with a short cut key

Probably the most convenient option; with the nautilus window in front, press a short cut key to move one directory up.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

# get information on the active window
front = get(["xprop", "-id", get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])])
# (only) if it is a "normal" nautilus window, take action
if 'WM_CLASS(STRING) = "nautilus", "Nautilus"' in front:
    # "virtually" press Ctrl + l
    run("xdotool key Control_L+l"); time.sleep(0.05)
    # copy the current path, calculate the "real" parent directory
    real = os.path.realpath(get(["xclip", "-o"]))
    up = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(real, os.pardir))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # enter the superior directory
    run("printf '"+up+"' | xclip -selection clipboard")
    run("xdotool key Control_L+v")
    # confirm by virtually press Return
    time.sleep(0.1)
    run("xdotool key Return")
```

#### To use

1. For this solution, both `xclip` and `xdotool` Need to be on your system.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdodool xclip
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `level_up.py` (anywhere).
3. Add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/level_up.py
   ```

***NB*** The shortcut options are a bit limited in this case, since the script *itself* will simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will make you log out... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> worked fine on my system.

#### Explanation

This script also simulates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but instead of using nautilus' `"NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"`, it uses `xclip` to copy the automatically selected path in the nautilus window. Like option 1, the script then calculates the real path and derives the superior directory.

This option might be useful if you prefer the keyboard to using right- click.

Answer (score 2):

Or for Ubuntu 14.04, nautilus 3.10-1, with the `xdotool` package added, just use the following in your `.local/share/nautilus/scripts/updirtree`
file:

```
# In nautilus, the pwd is the actual, not the link path
xdotool key ctrl-l
xdotool type "$(dirname $(pwd))" "
"
```

The final quote should just contain a newline or return (`0x0a`).
The `pwd` from within nautilus produces a different result than when run from a bash/terminal -- it returns the actual path, not the path using the link.

---

I agree it makes no sense, it's undocumented, and I can't even figure out what sort of execution environment is running the code (I can't find any shell which produces that result), but it works.  It's a hack, which is why I included the version of nautilus.  Who knows how long it will work?  Might break at the next nautilus upgrade (or the unknown interpreter), but for me, it works on links to mounted locations, links to places in the directory tree, or just plain locations in the directory tree.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 15.10 ... Can it work, maybe in a similar code?

Comment: This makes no sense,  `$(pwd)` is the working directory of the *shell*, not of *nautilus*. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto

Comment: @benos I confirm, it does work in 15.10

Comment: @JacobVlijm , It works well, it seems to me reasonable, nautilus runs scripts in the current directory.

Comment: Also @Sneetsher to my surprise, it works. You do have a timing issue however when used on very long paths. You'll need to set a break then, depending on the length of the path. Else typed paths appear to be broken.  At first, I fixed it with a (arbitrary) break, In the latest version, I made `xclip` *paste* the path, which is no subject to the length of the path.

Comment: Doesn't work in 15.10 (GNOME nautilus 3.14.2) however if that's executed in Bash I'm going to assume that `xdotool type "$(dirname "$PWD")" $'\n'` without the double quote on the last line would work as well. If it doesn't I'd assume that at least `$(pwd)` could be replaced with `$PWD`.

Answer (score 1):

A clean fix but needs source rebuild by reverting [this commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?h=gnome-3-12&id=6785caaf71f749c68de0e2671f4eca1cc474863f):

```
diff --git a/src/nautilus-mime-actions.c b/src/nautilus-mime-actions.c
index ca1f0ac..0b363b4 100644
--- a/src/nautilus-mime-actions.c
+++ b/src/nautilus-mime-actions.c
@@ -2029,21 +2029,13 @@ activate_activation_uris_ready_callback (GList *files_ignore,

    /* Convert the files to the actual activation uri files */
    for (l = parameters->locations; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
-       char *uri = NULL;
-
+       char *uri;
        location = l->data;

        /* We want the file for the activation URI since we care
         * about the attributes for that, not for the original file.
         */
-       if (nautilus_file_is_symbolic_link (location->file)) {
-           uri = nautilus_file_get_symbolic_link_target_uri (location->file);
-       }
-
-       if (uri == NULL) {
-           uri = nautilus_file_get_activation_uri (location->file);
-       }
-
+       uri = nautilus_file_get_activation_uri (location->file);
        if (uri != NULL) {
            launch_location_update_from_uri (location, uri);
        }
```

Build instructions:

1. Download source:

   ```
   apt-get source nautilus
   ```
2. Download build dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
   ```
3. Make the need modification from above patch

   Edit `src/nautilus-mime-actions.c`

   ```
   /* Convert the files to the actual activation uri files */
   for (l = parameters->locations; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
       char *uri = NULL;
       location = l->data;

       /* We want the file for the activation URI since we care
        * about the attributes for that, not for the original file.
        */
       if (nautilus_file_is_symbolic_link (location->file)) {
           uri = nautilus_file_get_symbolic_link_target_uri (location->file);
       }

       if (uri == NULL) {
           uri = nautilus_file_get_activation_uri (location->file);
       }

       if (uri != NULL) {
           launch_location_update_from_uri (location, uri);
       }
   ```
4. Build & install it

   ```
   autoreconf
   ./configure
   make
   ```

   To test without installation

   ```
   sudo killall -r "[\w]*nautilus"
   ./src/nautilus
   ```

   To install it

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

This will make nautilus resolve the links into their target path. BTW, this was reported as bug some time ago. If you think this is a feature then submit another bug report, asking for setting switch or specific shortcut for it.

**Reference:** [How can I stop Nautilus from dereferencing symlinks? [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280431/how-can-i-stop-nautilus-from-dereferencing-symlinks)

Comment: An issue could be that you either need to pin the current version of nautilus, or repeat the procedure after every update.

Comment: @JacobVlijm , yep that will be so if i build the deb package. But I didn't, it will be installed `/usr/local/bin/`, so the system will always run the modified copy, as listed in `$PATH`