# How to make Ubuntu File Manager show the "real" path after opening a shortcut link?

Tags: nautilus, 15.10, shortcuts, filemanager

When I open a link, instead of the real path, the file manager shows the location of the link file.

Example: home/Desktop/Link to html/wiki

[image: Bad Path]

What I would like the file manager to show is: /var/www/html/wiki

[image: Real Path]

How can I force the file manager to show the "real" path after opening a shortcut link?

Comment: this is one of the main reasons I will never use Nautilus. It is a very lacking file manager, and I cant believe it still hasn't been improved. The lack of navigation is terrible (no up arrow?!) Add to that there is no text entry field for this navigator and it almost becomes useless. You might want to check our SpaceFM. Its amazing.

Comment: See the properties

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I hope that Nautilus will be fixed in the future. Anyway, I will try SpaceFM out. :)

Comment: Related (a lot): http://askubuntu.com/questions/720491/nautilus-visited-directory-via-symlink-now-i-cant-go-one-level-up-in-the-targ/721558#721558

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a bind mount since linux 2.4

Test it with this:

```
sudo mount --bind /var/www/html /home/Desktop/html
```

Make it permanent by adding this line to your fstab after /home and /var:

```
/var/www/html /home/Desktop/html defaults,bind 0 0
```

Comment: And you have to do this for every symlink? Is there no more general solution?